# knife ec2 server create returning 403 Forbidden

Tags: amazon-ec2, knife, cookbook

I'm trying to install tomcat cookbook on an AWS instance, but is experiencing an error as below:

Role tomcat.rb:

```
name 'tomcat'
description 'A single tomcat server'
run_list(
  'recipe[tomcat]'
)
```

Running:

```
knife ec2 server create --availability-zone us-east-1d --node-name tomcat.demo --flavor t1.micro --image ami-fd20ad94 --identity-file .ssh/tiagov.pem --run-list 'role[tomcat]' --ssh-user ubuntu
```

Return:

```
...
...
ec2-54-237-233-176.compute-1.amazonaws.com   xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
ec2-54-237-233-176.compute-1.amazonaws.com 0 upgraded, 85 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ec2-54-237-233-176.compute-1.amazonaws.com Need to get 63.2 MB of archives.
ec2-54-237-233-176.compute-1.amazonaws.com After this operation, 184 MB of additional disk space will be used.
ec2-54-237-233-176.compute-1.amazonaws.com Err http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main libasound2 amd64 1.0.25-1ubuntu10.1
ec2-54-237-233-176.compute-1.amazonaws.com   403  Forbidden
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like your `update` endpoints might be out of date for the packages that you are installing when you are bootstrapping the instance. I would check that your `[tomcat]` recipe has the following command (as sudo):

```
apt-get update
```

I would also make sure that your ubuntu user in your AMI has sudo passwordless access for installation (this is the default for Amazon ubuntu AMIs)